# In Ticket to Ride, do cities have to be connected in the same order as on the ticket?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-europe

Is the direction of the ticket important? Do cities have to be connected in the order shown on the ticket?

For example, if I am attempting to claim the Rostov-Erzurum ticket, can I connect Erzurum to Rostov instead of connecting Rostov to Erzurum?

Comment: How could you connect Erzurum to Rostov without connecting Rostov to Erzurum?

Comment: By building the majority of the route from Erzurum outwards, or by first connecting Erzurum to the network that eventually also connects to Rostov.

Comment: @Nij, I don't see how that gives any ordering to the connection. At some point, you place a single section of track that causes the 2 cities to be connected. Whether that final section is directly connected to Rostov, directly connected to Erzurum, or simply connected somewhere in the middle in between the two, makes no difference.

Comment: The idea of "to" implies a "from". If the network is already connected with one city, it cannot be going *to* that city, since no *from* exists. But add the last link, and the network has come *from* the first city *to* the second.

Comment: But a from does exist... every track segment connects A and B. The from just isn't one of your 2 destination cities yet. This is consistent with both the rules of the game and be way English works. If someone builds an actual road from one city to another; you could either say "this road goes from city A to city B" or "this road goes from city B to city A", and both would be equally correct.

Comment: @tttppp, That question isn't about *Ticket to Ride: Europe*. That said, I've edited the leading answer to mention *Europe*, so everything should be ok now.

Comment: It's a circular argument to say the rules make the from-to relationship commutative, ahem that is the point of the question itself. And if you wish to use an origin somewhere in the existing network, then both the cities will be *from* that origin. You cannot use directional statements to explain a non-directional situation. "From X to Y" is not the same thing as "from Y to X" and neither is the same thing as "a non-directed route exists between the unordered pair X, Y".

Answer (score 5):

In both *Ticket to Ride* and *Ticket to Ride: Europe*, routes can be completed in any order, and there's no concept of direction of travel. All that matters is whether you can reach one of the cities from the other at the end of the game.

> If, by the end of the game, a player has created a continuous path of his color plastic trains between the two cities named on a Destination Ticket he holds, he scores the additional points indicated by the Point Value on the Ticket. If he has failed to complete a continuous path between those cities, he deducts the Point Value on the Ticket from his total score.

A *path between cities* must be created. Nothing about traveling *from* one of the cities *to* the other city.

For example, you could satisfy a Rostov-Erzurum ticket by having built Erzurum-Sevastopol, Rostov-Sochi, and Sevastopol-Sochi in any order.

---

[This](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/18119/2880) is a related question about Train Stations in *Ticket to Ride: Europe*.

Comment: Did you mean to say "routes can be completed in *any* order"?

Comment: @BJ Myers, Indeed! Fixed.

Comment: Why do you specify US and Europe version? Do you mean it's different in any other version?

Comment: @Andreas, The OP tagged TtoR, but used a TtoR:E example. To avoid confusion, I specified the answer applies to both. I can't speak for other versions.

Comment: Ok! Got it. I thought you knew something I didn't

Answer (score 3):

The direction of the connection doesn’t matter, just that the two cities are connected by a train path in your colour. It doesn’t even have to be the shortest route or the most direct route, as long as the path is uninterrupted between the two cities on the ticket.