# Claim different routes with a single station in Ticket to Ride Europe

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-europe

I know that a station can only be used to serve as a connection over another player's route between the station-city and another city.

But can a single station be used to claim different routes for different destination tickets or must the same (one) route be used for all of your destination tickets?

The rules are a bit unclear, but my understanding is that the same route must be used for all of your destination ticket.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper use of Stations - and how to convince others](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18119/proper-use-of-stations-and-how-to-convince-others)   The short answer is that a station can claim one route and that applies for all your tickets.  You can not use a different station route for different tickets.

Comment: @StartPlayer, The linked question is about whether the order of the name of the cities matter, and its answers doesn't answer this question. The linked question presupposes an answer to this question, but that doesn't make it a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each station allows you to claim a single route.

That route may be used to fulfill more than one destination ticket, but every ticket must use the same route.

From the rules,

> A Train Station allows its owner to use **one, and only one, of the routes** belonging to another player, into (or out of) that city to help him connect the cities on his Destination Tickets.
>
> If a player uses the same Station to help connect cities on several different Tickets, **he must use the same route into the city with the Station for all of those Tickets.** The Train Station owner does not need to decide which route he will use until the end of the game.

(Empahsis mine.)

For example, say you had the following three destination tickets:

- Frankfurt – Smolensk (Complete save for Frankfurt – Berlin)
- Amsterdam – Wilno (Complete save for Frankfurt – Berlin)
- Essen – Kyiv (Complete save for Essen – Berlin)

With a station at Berlin, you could complete either the first two destination tickets or the third, but not all three (unless you also had a station at Essen or Frankfurt).

[image: Clip of the relevant portion of the board]

The design of the station minis helps calculate the final points. At the end of the game, move each of your stations from its city onto the route it is claiming (on top of the cars). Then that one route counts as yours for the purposes of completing tickets. You don't get to move the station again, so you can't claim multiple routes. (Credit to [@Max](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/26692/max) for this tip.)

Comment: That was exactly what I meant. You were way more clear!

Comment: The design of the station minis is supposed to help with this. At the end of the game, move each of your stations from its city onto the route it is claiming (on top of the cars). Then that _one_ route counts as yours for the purposes of completing tickets. You don't get to move the station again, so you can't claim multiple routes.

Comment: @Max, Great tip! I've only played Europe digitally, so that never occurred to me. I've incorporated the tip into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no problem in having two stations (or even two parts of route) in common.

The only thing that is needed to claim a ticket is that the two stations are connected via a path of trains of your color.

The train station permits to use one opponent route to be counted as a route of yours. Once it is yours, you can use it for all of your tickets.

Comment: The train station permits to use one opponent route to be counted as a route of yours. Once it is yours, you can use it for all of your tickets.

Comment: Edited. You are right.