# Train Station doesn't work correctly in Ticket to Ride Europe [PC Version]

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-europe

1. I played the PC version of Ticket to Ride Europe recently.
2. I got the ticket / route for Paris to Athina.
3. I built a route from Paris --> Zurich --> Marseille --> Roma --> Palermo --> Smyrna
4. Other played put a route from Smyrna to Athina
5. I put a station on Smyrna, which should give me access to the route from Smyrna to Athina

According to [this post](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18119/the-proper-use-of-stations-in-ticket-to-ride-europe), my expectations of how the stations should work is correct.

Can someone explain what is happening? Is this just a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have it right: You should be able to use that station to complete the Paris-Athina route.

I'm guessing a reason the PC version fails here could be the fact that the end point of the borrowed line is at the end of your route and not connected to any of your trains. This might happen if the check-routes routine in the program saved time by only looking for gaps in your routes at stations and somehow a gap at the end (which isn't a "gap" under certain definitions).

But regardless of the reason, it is a bug. The gap can be at the end of the route. (This is confirmed in a different [question on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/533141/station-question).)

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I was flabbergasted when I saw the scoring, and it showed me failing this route.